# touch events on apple devices

Tags: javascript, ios, mobile

I use some third party software which creates an interactive book from a PDF. I can see how it works to a point but am not sure about making the mobile/tablet version work perfectly with links working on Apple devices..

The initial PDF has links created within it (done in Acrobat), the PDF is then imported and the web version created. 
The resulting javascript it creates for these links is as follows..

```
var pageEditor = [[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [],
[{
      annotype: "com.mobiano.flipbook.pageeditor.TAnnoLink",
      action: {
        triggerEventType: "mouseDown",
        actionType: "com.mobiano.flipbook.pageeditor.TAnnoActionOpenURL",
        url: "http://www.canal30apartments.com/360/viewer/mezz-lower.html"
      },
      location: { x: "0.085024", y: "0.067632", width: "0.184540", height: "0.180675" }
    },
    {
      annotype: "com.mobiano.flipbook.pageeditor.TAnnoLink",
      action: {
        triggerEventType: "mouseDown",
        actionType: "com.mobiano.flipbook.pageeditor.TAnnoActionOpenURL",
        url: "http://www.canal30apartments.com/360/viewer/mezz-upper.html"
      },
      location: { x: "0.764247", y: "0.694682", width: "0.174878", height: "0.180676" }
    }],
[{
    annotype: "com.mobiano.flipbook.pageeditor.TAnnoLink",
    action: {
      triggerEventType: "mouseDown",
      actionType: "com.mobiano.flipbook.pageeditor.TAnnoActionOpenURL",
      url: "http://www.canal30apartments.com/360/viewer/standard.html"
    },
    location: { x: "0.759417", y: "0.556518", width: "0.184540", height: "0.182609" }
  }],
[], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], [], []];
```

The `mousedown` event works on a Samsung device, but doesn't seem to work on Apple devices. I'd be interested as to whty this happens but mainly i'm asking if anyone could help as to how to alter the code to catch apple devices if there is a way?

All I could think of is..

```
triggerEventType:"touchstart"
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try `touchend` Event,
It might work on pure JS as I am using it in `Backbone.js`
And it works perfectly in `Backbone.js`

Comment: Thanks, but in this case 
    `{triggerEventType:"touchend"`
doesn't cause it to work on any mobile device